# extracting variable's innerhtml? using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, extract, innerhtml

I was trying to convert a whole document from javascript to jquery. So then I ran into a brick wall.

So on my script I have my array:

```
var phones = new Array();
phones[0] = 'http://www.cellunlocker.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/iphone-4.jpg" title="ipod" alt="ipod image';
phones[1] = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Blackberry-Bold-9650-Verizon.jpg/365px-Blackberry-Bold-9650-Verizon.jpg';
phones.push('http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/gadgetlab/2010/03/samsung-galaxys-536x536.jpg');
phones.push('http://handies.phandroid.com/media/motorola-spice-1286473916-630.jpg');
phones.push('http://www.pitchpoleenterprises.com/shop/ImageUnavailable.jpg');
```

And then I have my function as well:

```
function checkCase(){

    var phone = $('#cel')[0]; //document.getElementById('cel');
    var phone_div = $('#phone_display')[0]; //document.getElementById('phone_display');
```

Followed by the brick wall. I want to transform this particular code (currently commented as javascript). I tried a few things (with only the last ones being displayed there). Basically, I am trying to have the picture of the blackberry displayed. Right now, the image itself doesn't show up (the other pics work fine, because they are currently all in javascript), but I am trying to change them - and I have decided to start with the blackberry picture.

Basically, I do not know how to change the variable itself as jquery. Since it's a variable and not an id, I am completely lost in what to do.

```
case 'bb':
        /*phone_div.innerHTML*/ /*$('phone_div').html()*/ $('phone_div')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="'+phones[1]+'" title="blackberry" alt="blackberry image" />';
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes with this and a jsFiddle if possible?

Comment: Sure http://jsfiddle.net/ENqFb/

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ENqFb/1/. Note you were including two versions of jQuery. I just cleaned up what you had; didn't change any actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `phone_div` is a DOM element, if you want to get a jQuery wrapper around it just do it like this:

```
$(phone_div).html('<img src="'+phones[1]+'" title="blackberry" alt="blackberry image" />');
```

Also you should use the `html()` method as shown, otherwise I have no idea why you would jQuery at all, you could just as easily do:

```
phone_div.innerHTML = '<img src="'+phones[1]+'" title="blackberry" alt="blackberry image" />';
```

Really I don't even see why you are doing this:

```
var phone_div = $('#phone_display')[0];
```

This is very non-jQuery like.  You could just as easily eliminate this line of code altogether and just set teh html on that element like:

```
$('#phone_display').html('<img src="'+phones[1]+'" title="blackberry" alt="blackberry image" />');
```

That is the most "jQuery-like" approach to this.

Comment: Thank you very much! The coding works fine :) As for the reason why I want everything into jQUERY, it's because I am revising my work and trying to eliminate javascript altogether (although technically, jQUERY is javascript). In reality, I am trying to have my javascript commented, while my jquery would be my focus. I want to have both so that I can understand what I`m doing in both JS and JQ.

Comment: @MidevilChaos Be careful with that approach.  There are often times where basic javascript is a better solution to a problem than jQuery. When one becomes proficient in javascript, you will be able to identify these cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something link this to create a new img within the div

```
$('#phone_div').append('<img id="bb" src="'+phones[1]+'" />');
```

Comment: Thank you!. Counter intuitive for me this approach. Would not appending it mean that you would simply keep adding things?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You are adding elements within the div. I guess you should go with the .html("..") that was posted earlier

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you use it the following way:

```
// id selector (returns an array), you grep the first one
var phone_div = $('#phone_display')[0];
// not necessary, keep it to jQuery:
var phone_div = $('#phone_display');

// now this won't work at all, you use a string, 
// which would be interpreted as an DOM Element selector.
$('phone_div')[0]

// i guess you want it like this:
var phone_div = $('#phone_display');
phone_div.html(<img src="'+phones[1]+'" title="blackberry" alt="blackberry image" />);
```

Comment: Concerning the first portion, I did not realize that. Thank you.

I understand, a string. Gotcha! That makes a lot of sense.

As for the last part, you and someone else mentioned this. It works like a charm. Thanks to both of you :D